# Remove Link Pointing to Old Version of Program in Linux

Tags: linux, centos, command-line-interface, centos7

I installed Python 3 with:

```
yum install python3 -y
```

When I do:

```
which -a python3
```

I get:

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

Which is correct.

However, if I enter:

```
python3
```

I get:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/python3: No such file or directory
```

Apparently, python3 is still linking to a prior version which I have removed. How can I fix this so my system recognizes Python 3 being in /usr/bin/python3 instead of /usr/local/bin/python3.

Comment: Did you try restarting your terminal session after installing python?

Comment: That was the solution. If you want to post it as answer, I'll gladly accept it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with an updated PATH starting a new terminal session should pickup this change.

As stated on the comment section this was the case.

For completeness, if the new path (`/usr/bin/python3`) is stil not on your `PATH` on the new session you could manually add it on `/etc/profile` (globally) or `~/.bash_profile` (for your user, assuming you are using `bash`)